# In jQuery, is $(func) equivalent to $(document).ready(func)?

Tags: jquery

Is

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

the same as

```
$(function(){});
```

?

I believe it is, actually I'm 99% sure it is but wanted a 'second' opinion

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is the same.

**From the jQuery Docs - http://api.jquery.com/ready/**

> All three of the following syntaxes
>   are equivalent:
>
> • $(document).ready(handler)
>   • $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
>   • $(handler)

Answer (score 5):

Yes

"the `document-ready` idiom is so common, in fact that there's a shortcut version of it... The expanded version `$(document).ready` is arguably a better example of `self-documenting` code; it's much easier to see at a glance exactly what's going on - especially if it's buried in a page of another developers JavaScript!" - Borrowed from -  `jQuery Novice to Ninja`

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is. Personal preference.